# How to insert insert some sample data for this table in hive

Tags: hive

I am doing some practice myself and here is the table I created on hive, I want to add some sample data into it, can anyone help please?

What I tried is below:

```
INSERT INTO VALUES (
'John Smith', 
array('Toronto','Ontario', 'Canada'), 
named_struct('male', 38), 
map('Smith', 3)
);
```

Cannot convert column 2 from `struct male:int` to `struct sex:string,age:int`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution!

The issue was with struct field.

```
INSERT INTO family_head VALUES (
'John Smith', 
array('Toronto','Ontario', 'Canada'), 
s_struct('sex', 'male', 'age', 38), 
map('Smith', 3)
);
```

The result is like below:
[image]

I hope this is helpful to later readers.